# Django - Running tests gives django.db.OperationalError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

Recently, I decided to make a threaded function in Python that checks the output of a function and then updates the cache of the function accordingly. When I run my tests locally everything works as intended, but on the server I get the following.

```
OperationalError
database "test_ebdb" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 10 other sessions using the database.`
```

This is the threaded function that I use, it's going to query the database if the function it is calling queries the database.

```
def _check_and_update_cache(func, args, kwargs, cache_key, 
                            timeout=settings.DEFAULT_CACHE_TIMEOUT):
    """
    Runs the function that has been cached to see if the output is the same as 
    the one in the cache, if the output is not the same then it will 
    update the cache with the new result
    """
    new_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    old_result = cache.get(cache_key)

    if new_result != old_result:
        cache.set(cache_key, new_result, timeout)
```

This is the code that is calling it.

```
t = Thread(target=_check_and_update_cache, args=(func, args, kwargs, key,))
t.start()
```

Comment: Why are you running tests in production?

Comment: The error says your database has a limit on the number of sessions. So just increase that limit.

Comment: agree with @BishakhGhosh and for any other help include definition of all function you are using in your code; like mention what is the function of `func` in your code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman this is a on a Staging server

Comment: @BishakhGhosh I'll try that now

Comment: @Gahan I will in the future but the reason I didn't do it is because func is a very generic thing, it's passed in from a decorator

Answer (score 0):

So from the comments @BishakhGhosh was correct, I just had to increase the max_connections limit on my Postgres server and everything is fine now.

Thanks!